# SQL Request where I get the lastest result from a date

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I want to get the latest datetime from a table but also joining another table.

This is my first table :

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | ac |
| 3 | at |

And this is my second table :

| id | content | author | date | fk_term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202 | Maecenas ut massa ... | Renee Copnar | 2022-08-17 | 1 |
| 351 | Sociis natoque penatibus... | Rhona Levesque | 2022-10-30 | 1 |
| 557 | Phasellus in felis... | Kissie Blabber | 2022-09-11 | 1 |
| 383 | Maecenas tristique... | Saunders Robet | 2022-08-18 | 2 |
| 429 | In sagittis dui... | Jorey Strodder | 2022-12-21 | 2 |
| 655 | Maecenas ut massa... | Sim Harrod | 2023-01-07 | 2 |

And also I only want one result per first table id
Like this :

| content | author | date | fk_term | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sociis natoque penatibus... | Rhona Levesque | 2022-10-30 | 1 | a |
| Maecenas ut massa... | Sim Harrod | 2023-01-07 | 2 | ac |

Comment: Which column from first table is in the result?

Comment: Why don't you want the Sim Harrod row?

Comment: @nbk Maybe I'm missing something here, but there is no requirement for a pivot. That duplicate feels incorrect.

Comment: mb forgot to add the title to the result

Comment: @jarlh, I believe the ask here is to get the newest record for each `fk_term`, specifically for `fk_term=1`. Something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT st.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fk_term ORDER BY date DESC) as rn FROM second_table) st WHERE rn=1;` or what-have-you.

Comment: @JNevill the link has everything needed topivot static or dynamic, so it fits perfectly

Comment: @nbk It's a great link for pivot, however a pivot isn't the right solution to OPs question, so it's inappropriate. Instead maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011052/selecting-rows-with-the-highest-date or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user

Answer (score -1):

As one option: first get the latest record for each `fk_term`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM second_table st 
WHERE date = 
    (
        SELECT max(date) 
        FROM second_table
        WHERE st.fk_term = fk_term
    )
```

Then use that as a subquery to join:

```
 SELECT st2.content, st2.author, st2.date, st2.fk_term, ft.title
 FROM first_table ft
     INNER JOIN 
     (
        SELECT * 
        FROM second_table st 
        WHERE date = 
            (
                SELECT max(date) 
                FROM second_table
                WHERE st.fk_term = fk_term
            )
     ) st2
```